# blogger view for mobile shows well on pc,but wrongly on mobile

Tags: android, mobile, blogger

i have a responsive design on my blog and i activated some widgets to show on mobile,these widgets wont show when viewed from a mobile device but when viewed from a desktop it displays those widgets,here is what i mean

www.tricksbar,com?m=1 is supposed to show everything including widgets i enabled on mobile,but when views from a mobile device,it doesn't show,but when u enter same address on a desktop,it displays them properly

please any help for that?

i think its from my template but i don't want to change the template yet.